# Python doesn't install in wine on kali linux

Tags: installation, python, kali-linux, wine

I am trying to install python for windows in wine in my kali linux machine the problem is when I worte the command

```
wine msiexec /i python-2.7.16.msi
```

I recieved the following error:

```
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:msi:msi_install_assembly Failed to install assembly L"C:\\users\\root\\Temp\\msi5.tmp\\x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_x-ww_6f74963e.manifest" (0x80040154)
0009:err:msi:ACTION_InstallFiles Failed to install assembly
0009:err:msi:execute_script Execution of script 0 halted; action L"InstallFiles" returned 1603
0009:err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"InstallFinalize" returned 1603
0009:err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"ExecuteAction" returned 1603
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} could be created for context 0x1
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} not registered
0009:err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {f6d90f11-9c73-11d3-b32e-00c04f990bb4} could be created for context 0x1
```

and I don't know, what am I supposed to do to fix it.

How to fix it?

Comment: Firstly, why do you need Python to run in WINE of all things when Python should work natively on Kali and pretty much every flavour of Linux out there?

Comment: I write some programs in linux and I need to package them into a an exe file @Mokubai

Comment: If you have Kali Linux 2019.4, Python is already installed. If you have an older version, you can install it.  https://www.kalilinux.in/2019/08/install-python3-in-kali-linux.html

Comment: @John I want to install it in wine to have the windowx python version in my kali

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to install something called wine-python-2.7 via `apt-get install`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the right thing to do right here is to use the `wine64` version to install python:

```
wine64 msiexec /i python-2.7.10.amd64.msi
```

***Note:***

I also tried installing python via `apt-get install wine-python-2.7`. However, that did not fix the issue for me since an essential library `python27.dll` was missing:

```
0009:err:module:import_dll Library python27.dll (which is needed by L"C:\\Python27\\python.exe") not found
0009:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\Python27\\python.exe" failed, status c0000135
```